# jQuery - check if mousedown

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, mouseevent

I want to use http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ to impement Drag&Drop multi upload files into my website.

My problem is to animate same elements when mouse drag a files onto my site.
So I need to check if mouse has click button.

Something like:

```
$('#rozwin.scroller-off').live('mouseover',function(){
if( sme_event.mousedown() ) {
$(this).animate_something();
$('#upload_area').css({...}); //and change same css elements
}
});
```

Comment: Add a `mousedown` event handler, and set a boolean flag. Add a `mouseup` event handler and set the boolean flag to false. Check the state of that boolean value in your `mouseover` handler.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume the mouse will have a click button ;-)

Comment: @Blueman are you trying to drag a file from system and drop to a div?

Comment: @Imdad - yes. And when mouse is over same div I want to fire same action.

Comment: @Blueman try mouseup event handler

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('mousedown', '#rozwin.scroller-off', function() {
  alert('Mouse down happen');
});
```

Comment: It works only if I click on the DIV!
I want to drag a file from system and when dropping on same DIV on inactive browser windows (in that moment) I want to fire same event.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to drag file from system to a webpage, In this HTML5 will help you. 
Please refer https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_of_file_api_drag_drop_hard_drive_files_to_a_webpage28?lang=en